# Magento 2 how to create Single Time Picker

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, magento2.3, magento2.2.2

I know magento provides functionality like Single Time Picker:
[image]

How to do it? I found how to create date picker and date-time picker. But for my task, i should to create single time picker...

Comment: use time field type.

Answer (score 1):

**In your Xml File :-**

```
<field name="time_field">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Time</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">time_field</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Your_Module/js/form/element/time</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

> Create Custom Js For Time Picker :-

**Your/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/form/element/time.js**

```
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/date'
], function(Date) {
    'use strict';

    return Date.extend({
        defaults: {
            options: {
                showsDate: false,
                showsTime: true,
                timeOnly: true
            },

            elementTmpl: 'ui/form/element/date'
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I want to add time picker on frontend. @Rk Rathod can you please help?