# Magento 2 How to add time picker on custom form on frontend

Tags: magento2, datetime, timepicker

[image]

I want to add a time picker like the one in the image in a custom form on frontend.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/271014/72911

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154140/magento-2-show-timepicker-using-uicomponent-not-datepicker